# Facebook like button on pages that are accessible from multiple urls

Tags: facebook-like, multiple-domains

I have a website that is accessible from multiple domains, like `mydomain.com`, `mydomain.net`, `mydomain.org`, etc. and also I'm using rewrite to create search-engine friendly urls, like `/news/12345-news-alias` and only thing that is important in url is the item ID. So if you open `mydomain.com/news/12345` you will get the same page as if you open `mydomain.org/news/12345-news-alias`.

I've inserted facebook, twitter and Google+ like icons in my page, and the problem is that when you open `mydomain.com/news/12345` it shows 260 likes and if you open the same page via this address: `mydomain.org/news/12345-news-alias` it shows 0 likes.

What can I do to make facebook understand that these pages are the same?

Comment: What is the og:url meta tag set to on each of those pages?

Comment: It's dynamically changing with changing the url. I mean whatever that is in address-bar.

Comment: Well, that's your problem then.  Pick a URL for your page and stick with it.  If you have multiple aliases for the same page, it won't matter as long as the og:url in it is the same for the same page.

Comment: what `canonical` tag does? Can it be an alternative fix?

Comment: The canonical url should match your `og:url`.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I had a URL ("link1") with 4 likes. I changed the permalink to "link2". If I query the Facebook API for "link1" I get a JSON response with `"like_count": 4`. My `canonical url` and my `og:url` are both set as "link1". Still when I access link2, I get 0 likes.